# How to construct GQL to not contain a value from a set?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

Is it possible to select from a google app engine db where the key of a `db.Model` object is not in a given list?  If so, what would be the syntax?

Ex of a model class:

```
class Spam(db.Model):
    field1 = db.BooleanProperty(default=false)
    field2 = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Example of a query which I'd like to work but can't figure out:

```
spam_results = db.GqlQuery(
"SELECT * FROM Spam WHERE key NOT IN :1 LIMIT 10", 
['ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchMLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQYjAEM', 
 'ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchMLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQYjgEM'])

for eggs in spam_results:
  print "id: %s" % a.key().id()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No  Though app engine supports an "IN" query, it does not support a "NOT IN" query.

However, if your list of entities you *don't* want is small, then you might as well just retrieve *every* entity and filter out the ones you don't need yourself.

Alternatively, if the list of entities you want to exclude is a large fraction of all entities, then the above solution would be rather inefficient.  Instead, perhaps you could add an additional property to your model which you could use to filter out entities you don't want (whether or not this is possible will depend on your specific needs and data).

Comment: Thanks.  It's just as well anyway.  From the docs: "the IN operator executes a separate underlying datastore query for every item in the list [...] A maximum of 30 datastore queries are allowed for any single GQL query".  I'll just fetch a large number and sort out the ones I don't want programmaticly.