# NOT IN sql-like query google app engine not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

how to turn this:

```
Contact.gql('WHERE email IN :1', emails)
```

emails is a list of emais like: ["foo@example.com", "foo2@example.com"]

into this:

```
Contact.gql('WHERE email NOT IN :1', emails)
```

it raises an error:

```
BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Condition at symbol NOT
```

Comment: the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807591/how-to-construct-gql-to-not-contain-a-value-from-a-set

Answer (score 4):

It's not that it's not working, it's that you're trying something that isn't supported.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference